# Covering between universal covers

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

While trying to solve a problem, an intuitive idea has brought me to the following statement. Is it true? If yes, how can we prove it?

If $X$ is a covering space of $Y$, then the universal cover of $X$ is a covering space of the universal cover of $Y$.

Comment: Actually what happen is that if $X$ is a covering space of $Y$, then the universal cover of $X$ *is* also the universal cover of $Y$ (assuming the spaces are connected): that's why it is called *universal* cover. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers)

Comment: @Dario: Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: @Dario I think the adjective _universal_ refers to the fact that it covers every other covering of $X$, not what you state. Moreover, your claim needs $Y$ to be locally path-connected and semi-locally simply connected to be true.

Comment: @johndoe I think it is what I stated: if you have to space one of which cover the other, then they are covered by the same space. You are right about the other requirement, I assumed them since they are needed for the universal cover to exist.

Comment: @Dario the composition of two covering maps is not a covering map in general.

Comment: @johndoe Assuming local path-connectedness and semi-locally simply connectedness (conditions that you need for the existence of the universal covering) the composition of two covering map is a covering map. See for example Theorem 2.11 [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Jerzak.pdf)

Comment: @Dario This does not contradict what I said.

Comment: I'll put in a not so pedantic point that the term "the universal cover of a space" is a conceptual mistake; we can say "the universal cover", and "the fundamental group",  only for a **space with base point**. This is one reason for thinking in terms of the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1 X$ of a space; if $X$ is locally nice this may be topologised so that the  "star" of this  groupoid at $x \in X$, i.e. the space of arrows starting at $x$, is just the universal cover of $X$ at $x$.